# Flutter MouseRegion is not working when the child is a Chip Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

The mouse cursor in my flutter web program is not changing to a click cursor on hover when the child is a Chip widget. I changed the Chip to a Text and a Container widget and the mouse cursor changes without any issues.

Below is the code of the MouseRegion.

```
return MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Chip(
        backgroundColor: kLightPrimary,
        avatar: const Icon(
           Feather.phone_call,
           size: 18.0,
           color: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        label: Text(
          "Test num",
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: kPrimaryColor),
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `MouseRegion` and `GestureDetector` on a `Chip`, you want to use [`ActionChip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ActionChip-class.html) instead.

```dart
    ActionChip(
        onPressed() {/* use onPressed even if it would be empty */}
        backgroundColor: kLightPrimary,
        avatar: const Icon(
           Feather.phone_call,
           size: 18.0,
           color: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        label: Text(
          "Test num",
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: kPrimaryColor),
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
      )
```

Comment: It works perfectly man! :) Thank youu

Comment: The problem with ActionChip is that it prevents receiving the onTap even for parent widgets, like PopupMenuItem for example. If your parent should receive the onTap event, you can wrap ActionChip  with AbsorbPointer widget.

Answer (score 0):

Change your GestureDetector to InkWell this is working for me.

```
return  Container(
    width: 200,
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: InkWell( //use InkWell insted of GestureDetector 
      onTap: () {},
      child: Chip(
        backgroundColor: kLightPrimary,
        avatar: const Icon(
           Feather.phone_call,
           size: 18.0,
           color: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        label: Text(
          "Test num",
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: kPrimaryColor),
          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
      ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I have tried that, it's not working. the mouse cursor remains as default cursor on hover.